# How do I delete all strings after end of first string using VIM?

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file that has 5174 lines. The following are how the lines appear:

```
JAMES          1.664  1.664      1
JOHN           1.642  3.305      2
ROBERT         1.576  4.881      3
MICHAEL        1.321  6.202      4
MARY           1.319  7.521      5
WILLIAM        1.230  8.750      6
DAVID          1.185  9.934      7
RICHARD        0.854 10.788      8
CHARLES        0.765 11.552      9
JOSEPH         0.705 12.257     10
THOMAS         0.692 12.948     11
PATRICIA       0.539 13.486     12
CHRISTOPHER    0.519 14.005     13
LINDA          0.518 14.523     14
BARBARA        0.490 15.013     15
```

I am using within VIM:

```
:s/^\s*//g
```

This did not work. How do I delete all of the characters immediately after the first character in every line?

Comment: Output? I can't tell if you want `J` or `JAMES` for the first line.

Comment: Can you correct what I am doing incorrectly to add those characters to the beginning and end of JAMES?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this in vim:

```
:%s/\([^[:blank:]]\+\).*/\1/
```

`\([^[:blank:]]\+\)` will match and group text before first white-space and back-reference `\1` will substitute that in replacement.

Comment: So, let me see if I understand correctly: %s is search and replace, \([^[:blank:]]\+\).* is that it starts with 1 or more blanks followed by any character 0 or more times, and \1 means the same string as in the escaped parenthesis in the 1st string?

Comment: I clicked on the up arrow but I need a 15 or higher reputation. I have a new account, so how else do I mark this as answered?

Comment: Do you have any ideas on the second part of my question?

Comment: Can you correct what I am doing incorrectly to add those characters to the beginning and end of JAMES?

Comment: With the edit you have changed nature of the question completely. Earlier problem was to print only first word before a whitespace in each line. I suggest you post a new problem for this new problem and you will get better answers.

Comment: I have asked a new question about this.

Answer (score 3):

Many ways to skin this cat…

with a substitution:

```
:%s/\w\+\zs.*
```

with `:normal`:

```
:%norm! f D
```

Comment: Can you correct what I am doing incorrectly to add those characters to the beginning and end of JAMES?

Answer (score 0):

You already have a solution but macros can also be a way to do it:

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

- <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> start recording a macro in the `q` register
- <kbd>e</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> go one character after the end of the word
- <kbd>D</kbd> delete the end of the line
- <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> go at the beginning of the bottom line
- <kbd>q</kbd> stop recording the macro

Then you can do `5174@q` in normal mode to replay the macro 5174 times and delete all the lines.